# getting libraries for eclipse(android)

Tags: android, eclipse

I need some libraries for my application (WiFi)

The libraries are:

```
import android.net.wifi.p2p.WifiP2pManager
import android.net.wifi.p2p.nsd.WifiP2pDn
import android.net.wifi.p2p.nsd.WifiP2pDn
```

Comment: and? what is a question?

Comment: Yes...so what is the issue?? What is the question??

Comment: The question is the compiler give me error in these libraries " import android.net.wifi.p2p.WifiP2pManager.DnsSdTxtReco cannot be resolved"                                                          thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These classes are available from API level 18 (Jelly Bean 4.3). You cannot obtain them in a separate library, they come packaged with the system libs. Declare your app to use this version and the imports will be resolved automatically.

```
<!-- In the AndroidManifest.xml of your project -->
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="18"
      android:targetSdkVersion="18"
      android:maxSdkVersion="18" />
```

Reflection on comment:

> The error is The import
>   android.net.wifi.p2p.WifiP2pManager.DnsSdTxtRecordListener cannot be
>   resolved –

Add `import android.net.wifi.p2p.WifiP2pManager.*` to import every inner class of WifiP2PManager.

Tip: Eclipse organizes your imports automatically if you press CTRL+SHIFT+O or CMD+SHIFT+O. Place the cursor on the error and press CTRL+1. You should have the import ... class option.

Comment: I tried them but the error still require the libraries.

Comment: The error is The import android.net.wifi.p2p.WifiP2pManager.DnsSdTxtRecordListener cannot be resolved

Comment: The error is " The import android.net.wifi.p2p.WifiP2pManager.DnsSdTxtRecordListener cannot be resolved"

Comment: Have you ever downloaded the latest sdk?